# Typo3: Where can i get list of TCA types?

Tags: reference, typo3, customization

I have bodytext and image so like this type of list where can I found? Can I get page list in select box?

`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['text_image_left'] = [
        'showitem' => '
      --palette--;palette.general;general,
        header, subheader, header_layout,menu,
        bodytext;bodytext_formlabel,
      --div--;tabs.images,
        image,
      --div--;tabs.appearance,
                --palette--;palette.frames;frames,
      --div--;tabs.access,
        hidden;field.default.hidden,
      --div--;tabs.extended
    ',
        'columnsOverrides' => ['bodytext' => ['config' => ['enableRichtext' => true]]]
    ];`

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to make it more clear? (Questions and answers can be helpful for others in the future too ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, not sure if I get your question right. You asked
 1. for a list of TCA types
 2. how to get a list of pages in a select field (?)

You can find the complete TCA Documentation here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/

Interesting part for you is the [column][*][config] part:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Index.html

In order to create a select with a page list, you need following kind of configuration.
I would suggest to use "group" type for field.

```
'page' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'List of Pages',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'group',
        'internal_type' => 'db',
        'allowed' => 'pages',
        'size' => 1,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 1,
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, now I am using [Mask](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask/) Plugin. It provides all fields.